# Multiple hovers with text on a single image

Tags: html, css, weebly

Okay, right off the bat, I'm very inexperienced at code editing.  But I'm doing a project for National History Day in the website category, and I wanted to include a picture of the constellations, but when you hover over each constellation, it would have some text show up giving a description about it.  Since the picture I'm using has about twenty different constellations (here's the image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JwZpaRYS5CQ/VmODU-UdAUI/AAAAAAAAAXE/FlzXIYCit_A/w2234-h1110-no/vizcon.gif), is there any way to do this? I could probably make an image map, but I'm not wanting the constellation to be a link to anywhere.

These are the image map coordinates, which are a general area around each constellation, but I didn't put anything for the links.

```
<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JwZpaRYS5CQ/VmODU-UdAUI/AAAAAAAAAXE/FlzXIYCit_A/w2234-h1110-no/vizcon.gif" width="1000" height="550" /><map id="imgmap201512519617" name="imgmap201512519617">
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="30,82,185,219,287,191,190,120,186,119" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="347,314,340,396,478,439,448,312,384,349,474,437,382,353,383,351,378,347" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="5,431,92,441,129,421,139,435,93,446,96,527,195,594,240,562,249,579,188,605,82,534,2,537" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="10,619,25,633,58,634,77,616,50,589,22,593,17,609,6,609" href="" target="" /><area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="447,555,392,654,437,646,537,689,481,581" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt=""title=" "coords="265,677,191,630,138,635,101,704,98,757,82,779,49,765,44,800,92,807,122,755,184,705,253,710,251,687,170,688,116,738,122,695,158,656,195,656,257,691" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="393,719,304,757,215,744,264,820,344,854,393,768,395,738" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="587,808,554,822,505,828,517,876,607,911,614,874,645,870,642,844,607,844" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="868,482,853,532,878,537,893,562,829,657,756,559,682,540,658,613,716,747,682,745,606,649,587,664,681,771,736,772,798,731,840,676,915,563,890,530,899,496" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="561,348,581,362,561,374,554,407,526,413,535,371,551,368" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="415,497,448,502,469,511,461,524,412,505" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="335,519,361,523,367,566,352,559,350,536,333,535" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="675,304,633,375,643,388,719,386,736,421,716,455,643,419,612,433,621,446,648,444,709,468,705,536,726,549,818,493,791,409,792,363,835,297,802,298,779,356,725,366,659,361,699,315" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="850,415,861,418,867,447,900,444,905,432,893,414,905,408,927,438,901,465,860,469,845,438" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="959,345,925,402,1033,500,982,542,1009,563,1052,511,1102,516,1085,488,1050,495,1023,423,1029,355" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="687,892,643,929,682,963,780,949,775,894,811,840,851,816,851,836,874,833,854,767,829,775,839,799,779,835,750,891,748,936,685,935,713,907" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="925,891,906,895,915,930,924,947,885,916,843,904,841,936,895,949,916,984,984,961,975,925,937,923,940,891" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="934,696,882,745,952,805,999,755" href="" target="" /><area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="985,667,982,690,1042,690,1036,721,1154,733,1221,658,1270,655,1323,629,1326,582,1299,581,1290,619,1217,642,1200,609,1189,551,1153,550,1173,604,1114,626,1065,610,970,611,982,636,1083,644,1126,666,1179,634,1199,650,1129,701,1060,701,1054,665" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1221,749,1212,823,1287,824,1272,760" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1050,819,1058,848,1144,818,1310,903,1370,877,1400,838,1424,774,1482,782,1488,743,1526,763,1577,702,1600,626,1631,601,1643,634,1669,625,1658,584,1609,583,1566,618,1536,697,1519,728,1474,709,1450,748,1384,738,1363,819,1298,863,1147,790,1095,805" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1547,464,1521,485,1477,476,1503,520,1500,550,1556,569,1531,598,1364,543,1290,544,1289,513,1363,475,1455,484,1463,456,1521,445" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1625,427,1633,494,1599,563,1628,567,1647,518,1659,518,1688,591,1708,584,1661,481,1646,477,1648,430" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1774,565,1738,603,1760,622,1795,586,1784,570" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1760,401,1719,447,1801,519,1872,544,1930,477,1841,444" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="635,283,707,283,699,231,670,225,735,177,807,218,943,239,1228,158,1363,173,1348,121,1222,120,911,192,717,149,633,207" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1083,295,1106,296,1144,250,1266,237,1297,269,1300,312,1478,365,1488,310,1321,290,1316,258,1504,230,1549,287,1606,326,1639,290,1560,255,1554,225,1679,217,1671,184,1540,168,1364,182,1252,220,1114,231" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1219,1042,1217,1053,1182,1055,1192,1083,1232,1080,1233,1106,1268,1109,1247,1072,1281,1069,1275,1051,1237,1054,1244,1038" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1837,716,1807,756,1842,768,1804,822,1768,851,1791,874,1812,839,1833,868,1847,852,1826,825,1865,769,1916,788,1915,763,1858,750" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2018,746,1975,763,1940,787,1961,816,1996,803,2037,812,2041,791,1998,783,1993,771,2037,765" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="1978,556,1928,582,1960,663,1948,726,2044,709,1994,645,2011,602,2052,598,2040,632,2066,632,2070,588,2056,555,2056,541,2066,533,2041,530,2050,581,2004,586,1984,566" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2421,1046,2399,1060,2367,1014,2328,1020,2288,935,2258,937,2217,970,2161,911,2102,884,2159,799,2192,781,2241,781,2254,795,2274,748,2255,714,2186,723,2147,761,2079,675,2057,694,2029,685,2020,664,2056,667,2065,648,2092,655,2153,718,2180,690,2274,691,2302,743,2298,794,2262,826,2213,808,2181,825,2143,873,2189,884,2220,926,2262,905,2300,903,2344,989,2377,988" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2522,782,2376,765,2355,706,2276,640,2276,619,2237,617,2245,559,2286,552,2331,572,2306,620,2377,696,2430,683,2473,702" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2140,611,2160,610,2155,560,2227,584,2225,554,2121,523,2112,502,2194,468,2165,445,2100,487,2011,436,2065,403,2026,304,1911,298,1912,377,2068,500,1953,471,1949,506,2076,533,2111,537,2140,553,2122,606" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2345,462,2354,520,2410,500" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2246,374,2265,361,2246,286,2289,263,2286,231,2210,265,2170,323,2138,356,2152,434,2194,420,2182,390,2167,391,2167,358,2225,296,2228,359" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2377,170,2361,190,2427,224,2477,218,2516,244,2571,223,2570,202,2514,225,2498,196,2428,195" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2405,278,2385,291,2508,407,2353,317,2346,359,2522,441,2557,444,2547,545,2571,537,2571,406" href="" target="" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="2577,582,2459,574,2388,597,2468,491,2464,478,2495,486,2507,469,2452,413,2422,436,2440,475,2435,495,2394,543,2343,636,2411,615,2477,594,2572,616" href="" target="" />
```

Comment: Can you post the code, or a link to a jsfiddle?

Comment: You won't be able to escape defining 'hotspots' that need to be triggered. Maybe position `absolute` elements on the image over which you can hover. Here's a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/alexmorris/pen/iaKkH)

Comment: @RenevanderLende What you linked me looks closest to what I've been trying to find, thank you.  Can the shape be changed from circles to a transparent blob? What I was trying to highlight in the picture was just a general area around each constellation that could show the names of them or a description when it was hovered over.

Comment: @k97513 it's on a weebly site

Comment: Oh. Well in that case, can you post the weebly link?

Comment: Try working with jQuery UI.

Comment: @k97513 The weekly link doesn't really have anything on it, because I was unsure on how to go about doing this picture.  Should I just make places to hover on top of the picture? I'm nott sure what to do.

Comment: @Aslen Whitmore yes you can, instead of an image (a SVG in the pen) you can do `li { .... background: transparent ....}` and `li a { ... color: black ... }` and you should be good to go... BTW DO post some progress in your question, I sure would like to know the result!!

Comment: Now that I think of it, when you create the GIF yourself, it might be interesting to create a SVG instead with Inkscape or something like that. That way you can give each constellation an ID as they will be polygon paths (and on ID's you can hover). Just a thought....

Comment: @RenevanderLende Okay!! I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: @Aslen Whitmore Ix saw this [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/shiva112/pen/bEGzav), just what the doctor ordered!!! SVG map with CSS markers

Comment: @RenevanderLende Wow! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @RenevanderLende So a question about that codepen demo, is it possible to make more than one marker for different shapes?  I understand how the marker part works, but can you make a lot of different shaped transparent markers for each corresponding constellation? I wasn't sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Good question, but it is not my **pen**. You should ask the developer at codepen, I guess. He's Dutch, like me, so if you can't communicate with him, just get back here and I'll help out.

Comment: Had a quick look, you can give each marker a background image and, yes, you can make multiple marker for one constellation (for each star). Simply treat a constellation as a country (like the pen) and it should work fine. **Start simple**, make a simple marker first and test it with hover and such, before digging into more elaborate fancyness. Baby steps...

Comment: And yet another good example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Ywqajy). Now with irregular SVG shapes...